# Expressplay.framework is giving linking error - xcode - ios

Tags: ios, xcode, drm

I'm using Expressplay SDK for playing DRM contents. I have linked the Expressplay.framework to my iOS project. But while building its giving linking error

Below .h and .mm files

### iosdrm.h file

```
#import <ExpressPlay/ExpressPlay.h>
// import RCTBridgeModule
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>)
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#elif __has_include(“RCTBridgeModule.h”)
#import “RCTBridgeModule.h”
#else
#import “React/RCTBridgeModule.h” // Required when used as a Pod in a Swift project
#endif

#define EXP_INIT_ASYNC  1

typedef enum {
  DRMCommandStatus_NO_RESULT = 0,
  DRMCommandStatus_OK,
  DRMCommandStatus_CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_IO_EXCEPTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_INVALID_ACTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_JSON_EXCEPTION,
  DRMCommandStatus_ERROR
} DRMCommandStatus;

@interface iosdrm : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
{
  UIAlertView* alertView;
  NSMutableData *receivedData;
  long responseCode;
  NSMutableArray* proxies;
  NSDictionary * cdvCommand;
}
// @property(nonatomic, readonly) WSB_PlaylistProxy* proxy;
@end
```

#pragma mark - Private methods

```
 WSB_Result EXP_Initialize(void (^callback)(WSB_Result initialization_result))
 {
     // initialize the Wasabi runtime
     WSB_Result result = WSB_Runtime_Initialize();
     if (result != WSB_SUCCESS) {
         NSLog(@"Failed to initialize Wasabi Runtime: %d", result);
         return result;
     }

     // check if we're already personalized, without blocking
     if (WSB_Runtime_IsPersonalized()) return WSB_SUCCESS;

     // personalize in a separate thread
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         // personalize and block until we're done
         WSB_Result result = WSB_Runtime_Personalize(nil, 0);
         NSLog(@"Wasabi Personalization result: %d", result);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ callback(result); });
     });

     return EXP_INIT_ASYNC;
 }
```

The

### iosdrmManager.mm

```
#import "iosdrm.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
// import RCTBridge
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridge.h>)
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#elif __has_include(“RCTBridge.h”)
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#else
#import "React/RCTBridge.h" // Required when used as a Pod in a Swift project
#endif

// import RCTEventDispatcher
#if __has_include(<React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>)
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#elif __has_include(“RCTEventDispatcher.h”)
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#else
#import "React/RCTEventDispatcher.h" // Required when used as a Pod in a Swift project
#endif

struct Node
{
  WSB_PlaylistProxy* proxy;
};

static void EXP_OnPlaylistProxyEvent(void* instance, const WSB_PlaylistProxy_Event* event)
{
  // instance not used in this example
  switch (event->type) {
    case WSB_PPET_ERROR_NOTIFICATION:
      WSB_PlaylistProxy_ErrorNotificationEvent* e;
      e = (WSB_PlaylistProxy_ErrorNotificationEvent*)event;
      NSLog(@"Error notification from Playlist Proxy: %d, %s",
            e->result, e->error_string);
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}

static dispatch_queue_t RCTGetMethodQueueDRM()
{
  // We want all instances to share the same queue since they will be reading/writing the same database.
  static dispatch_queue_t queue;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("drmQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
  });
  return queue;
}

@implementation iosdrm
@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

// Export a native module
// https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(lstdrm);

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
  return RCTGetMethodQueueDRM();
}

// Export constants
// https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/native-modules-ios.html#exporting-constants
- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
  return @{
           @"EXAMPLE": @"example"
         };
}

// Return the native view that represents your React component
- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[UIView alloc] init];
}

 #pragma mark - Private methods

 WSB_Result EXP_Initialize(void (^callback)(WSB_Result initialization_result))
 {
     // initialize the Wasabi runtime
     WSB_Result result = WSB_Runtime_Initialize();
     if (result != WSB_SUCCESS) {
         NSLog(@"Failed to initialize Wasabi Runtime: %d", result);
         return result;
     }

     // check if we're already personalized, without blocking
     if (WSB_Runtime_IsPersonalized()) return WSB_SUCCESS;

     // personalize in a separate thread
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         // personalize and block until we're done
         WSB_Result result = WSB_Runtime_Personalize(nil, 0);
         NSLog(@"Wasabi Personalization result: %d", result);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ callback(result); });
     });

     return EXP_INIT_ASYNC;
 }
```

while building i'm getting the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_WSB_Runtime_Initialize", referenced from:
      EXP_Initialize(void (int) block_pointer) in iosdrmManager.o
  "_WSB_Runtime_IsPersonalized", referenced from:
      EXP_Initialize(void (int) block_pointer) in iosdrmManager.o
  "_WSB_Runtime_Personalize", referenced from:
      ____Z14EXP_InitializeU13block_pointerFviE_block_invoke in iosdrmManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

Seems to suggest you are building for the emulator, instead of for an actual device. The library will likely not work on the emulator (neither does FairPlay, or any other DRM library that i know of). Make sure you are building for an actual iOS device (which should have some variant of arm architecture).

Comment: i'm building for actual device, please help me with this

Comment: @OK200 Then you might try and enable this: https://samwize.com/2015/01/14/what-is-build-active-architecture-only/

Comment: @OK200 Then you are definitely building for the simulator for some reason. Can you post a screenshot of the top bar of your XCode?

Comment: @OK200 And i presume you running it by pressing play?And yes, it would run after removing the code, as normally you can easily build against the simulator, but DRM libraries are different. Have you checked your build settings under Architectures? What is that set to?

Comment: yes i have no idea on this, it was working good until few weeks back.

Comment: I will completely remove the project and build from beginning so that it may not happen

Comment: I have completely removed the project and  build again. It's giving error. I have checked with Expressplay support. If they revert back. I'll update here.